# LG WT4801CW washer grinding noise

Tags: washing-machine

When the inside tub rotates, there's a grinding sound.  When I turn the rotor assembly from the bottom of the washer, it also has a grinding sound. After I remove the rotor assembly and turn the tub, no grinding sound.  If I put the rotor assembly on the 
Some of the side coils on the stator (the side that touches the side of the rotor) appear to be nicked or slightly broken/bent. I also see a few small bb's/bearings on the inside of the rotor assembly (in between some of the magnets and on the magnets).  I also received an LE error code when the machine was running.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: your ball bearing has failed, replace it, or live with reduced life+efficiency and greater noise.